# plotly - how to collapse axis at defined cutoff

Tags: python, graph, plotly

I'm trying to create a graph that focuses on the 99% of the data that is w/in a given range, meaning that there are 1% outliers that skew the perspective/"ability to zoom in on."  Please see the attached picture showing what I'm going for.  Basically, I want to collapse a portion of the y-axis.  I am using python if that matters.  If it's not possible to do this in plotly, I can switch to another library if you know of one.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust the range of your y-axes from the layout. For example:

```
layout['yaxis']['range'] = [-5, 15]
```

Comment: thanks for the thought, but this would exclude points > 15.  I still want to include those points, just not have the y-axis scaled against them.  The y-axis would really have 2 scalings, 1 below the squiggly line (in the attached pic) and 1 above it.  The finished plot would not exclude any points.

Comment: @user2426679 if you click on "Autoscale"  you would view all your data (given you have points > max_range).   However, if you want to see all your data at once while having your plot zoomed in on a specific part, you might want to use subplots with shared x-axes: https://plot.ly/python/subplots/#subplots-with-shared-x-axes